# Does IdentityServer4 offer Identity Brokering?

Tags: identityserver4

I am currently working on a project where we need to integrate with another companies Identity Provider.  I noticed that the product the other company is using KeyCloak (https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/server-adminstration-guide/content/topics/identity-broker.html) provides a feature known as Identity Brokering.  Does IdentityServer4 have anything like this?  One feature of IdentityServer4 that seemed like it may be of some use is the External Identity Providers integration (http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/signin_external_providers.html) but there is no documentation available or so it seems.  Any help would be appreciated as we are now at the crossroads and need to decide if IdentityServer4 is going to fulfill all of our use cases.

Comment: Accoriding to Key cloak they are using OpenIdConnect, and OAuth so you should be able to integrate with them fine

Answer (score 1):

There is no documentation but there is working sample code in the [quickstart UI](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/release/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs#L159-L272) sample.